# Roslyn - Parse string to MethodDeclarationSyntax

Tags: roslyn

Is there any function in Roslyn, by which I can parse my string as a MethodDeclarationSyntax?

I have a file which contains the method declaration, so I am reading that file content to string and now I want to create a Method from that string. Any suggestions?

Comment: There are various `Syntax.Parse*` methods, but I can't find anything that would parse a method declaration.

Comment: yaa... even I couldn't..

Comment: Probably added a lot later, but now there's `ParseMemberDeclaration`, which will handle method declarations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to parse your string as "C# Script", an experimental version of C# that allows top-level method declarations. Doing:

```
var tree = SyntaxTree.ParseText("void Foo() {}", options: new ParseOptions(kind: SourceCodeKind.Script));
```

Gives you a valid syntax tree that contains a `CompilationUnitSyntax` of a single method declaration.